# Throttle bandwidth in PHP

Tags: php, bandwidth, throttling

Is there a way to throttle delivery of a page in pure PHP ?

I know it can be done for a download file, but I was looking for an implementation for general HTML pages.

I was looking for perhaps a header type that can be sent

```
header('Throttle:300kb-ps')
```

Comment: add sleep functionality to your code? but I don't know why you want to slow down a page

Comment: for sleep to really throttle bandwidth you'd have to have it implicitly flush, like stream the output in chunks.  Otherwise it will just take longer to flush the output but the bandwidth would be the same.

Comment: This seems like it might be what you are after, http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-throttle.php. You may want to check the users connection speed first though, that would require an ajax request.

Comment: thanks guys, an example for throttling is when you manage multiple sites and clients, and they don't pay their bills. Turning off a site is a harsh thing to do, also some clients pay more than others. I'm not just talking about standard sites, this is more to do with APIs and web services where I have most of my clients

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I think the prob with sleep is that it uses more cpu than just throttling. (I think)

Comment: I don't think you can throttle. If it's for apis and web services, I'd rate limit them. When they've done n requests in last t seconds, return Server Busy.

Comment: @imel96 good point for api access, what about pages. If my client has a portal on my cms, and they conduct business on that site. I was just thinking to throttle the speed until they paid their account.
The portal access they get allows them to sell goods online. I'm also assuming they are not on-purposely not paying, that's why id rather limit than stop access

Answer (score 2):

It's possible if you would use the stream API (e.g. `fwrite()`). Then you could register a token bucket stream filter. I've compiled that all for you in [`bandwidth-throttle/bandwidth-throttle`](https://github.com/bandwidth-throttle/bandwidth-throttle):

```
use bandwidthThrottle\BandwidthThrottle;

$out = fopen("php://output", "w");

$throttle = new BandwidthThrottle();
$throttle->setRate(100, BandwidthThrottle::KIBIBYTES); // Set limit to 100KiB/s
$throttle->throttle($out);

fwrite($out, "<html>Your page</html>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [apache mod_ratelimit](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_ratelimit.html) if you want to "bandwidth rate limit" pages. It works per request, so you need to figure out to whom is a request destined to and then set the limit as required.

The web server is the place to do this, you only need to use php to control it.

Also, as per my comment, if it's for APIs and web services, I'd "request rate limit" them. When they've done n requests in last t seconds, return Server Busy.

Bandwidth rate limiting only effective for large responses, like for KBs of data transfer. For small responses, like API responses, it won't have any effect.